# How to keep the button active after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons that show and hide inputs when one of them selected. If the form is submitted when the oneway button is selected, the form reloads with an active return button. How do i get the active label(button) to still be active after the page reload/refresh?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label[name='oneway']").on("click", function() {
    $(".arrival").hide();
    $(".from").removeClass('col-lg-3');
    $(".from").addClass('col-lg-4');
    $(".to").removeClass('col-lg-3');
    $(".to").addClass('col-lg-4');
    $(".departure").removeClass('col-lg-3');
    $(".departure").addClass('col-lg-4');
    $("label[name='return']").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#trip').val('0');
  });

  $("label[name='return']").on("click", function() {
    $(".arrival").show();
    $(".from").removeClass('col-lg-4');
    $(".from").addClass('col-lg-3');
    $(".to").removeClass('col-lg-4');
    $(".to").addClass('col-lg-3');
    $(".departure").removeClass('col-lg-4');
    $(".departure").addClass('col-lg-3');
    $("label[name='oneway']").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#trip').val('1');
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label for="oneway" class="btn btn-default " name="oneway">One way</label>
    <label for="return" class="btn btn-default active" name="return">Return</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 from">
      <label for="From">From</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" id="from" name="from" placeholder="Departure city" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 to">
      <label for="To">To</label>
      <input type="text" name="to" class="form-control autocomplete" id="to" placeholder="Arrival city" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 departure">
      <label for="DepartureDate">Departure Date</label>
      <div class="input-group date">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <input id="date_added" type="text" name="dd" class="form-control" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 arrival">
      <label for="ArrivalDate">Arrival Date</label>
      <div class="input-group date">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <input id="date_modified" type="text" name="rd" class="form-control" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row col-lg-12">
      <button type="submit" name="confirm" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " id="confirm">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: use `localStorage`

Comment: all examples of localStorage i could find were single button toggle and didn't work in this case

Comment: really? every localStorage example was for a single button - perhaps sessionStorage examples use two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the state of the button throughout page reloads using `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`.

---

**sessionStorage:**

> The `sessionStorage` property accesses a session Storage object for the current origin. `sessionStorage` is similar to `localStorage`; the difference is that while data in `localStorage` doesn't expire, data in `sessionStorage` is **cleared when the page session ends**.
>
> - Opening a page in a **new tab or window** creates a **new session** with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.

More about `sessionStorage`  here [developer.mozilla.org/Window/sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

---

**localStorage:**

> The read-only `localStorage` property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is **saved across browser sessions**. `localStorage` is similar to `sessionStorage`, except that while data stored in `localStorage` has **no expiration time**, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.
>
> - It should be noted that data stored in either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` is **specific to the protocol of the page**.
> - The **keys and the values** are **always strings** (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

More on `localStorage` here: [developer.mozilla.org/Window/localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

---

Here is the code **example**:

```
$("label[name='oneway']").on("click", function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("btnActive", "oneway");
    ....
 });

$("label[name='return']").on("click", function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("btnActive", "return");
});

let sessionState = sessionStorage.getItem("btnActive");

if( sessionState !== null ) {
    if( sessionState == "oneway" ) {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

Or using `localStorage`:

```
// set
localStorage.setItem("btnActive", "oneway");
// get
localStorage.getItem("btnActive");
```

Comment: @OtunMusaBashir Your welcome, glad it worked for you.